# Are there any .NET tools available to mux / demux MP4 streams?

Tags: .net, mp4

Are there any .NET-specific tools out there that can parse / access the elementary data streams in an MP4 file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the kind of thing you meant, but: MeGUI (a GPL'ed video encoding/muxing application written in C#) includes [a frontend for mp4box](http://megui.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/megui/megui/trunk/packages/mux/mp4/MP4BoxMuxer.cs?view=markup) (a commandline MP4 muxer/demuxer).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a codec that will play MP4 streams, then you could use the unmanaged DirectShow api and you should be able to get info through there.

There is a project for a managed wrapper to DirectShow, which you can find here:

http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/[link text](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/)